# Lucas-Lehmer test using Python not working for large numbers

Tags: python, largenumber, primality-test

I am trying to write a function that should take in a Mersenne number and return whether it is a prime number or not using the Lucas-Lehmer primality test. I am trying to return the last number generated in the Lucas-Lehmer sequence which should be 0 if it is a prime number

[image: Lucas Lehmer sequence]

I have written the following function to do the above

```python
def lucas_lehmer_modified(p):
   M=2**p-1
   for i in range (0,p-1):
     if i == 0:
       x = 4
     else : 
        x = (prev**2-2)%(M)
     prev=x
   return x
```

My problem is that this code works for small numbers such as `127` but not for large numbers like `2305843009213693951` and even for `524287`. My Python Jupyter notebook hangs up. Any advice on how I can get a function that takes in a Mersenne prime as an input and returns whether it is a prime number or not using the Lucas Lehmer test. I need to make it work for at least `2^65-1`

Comment: Where do you run the Jupyter notebook? Locally or on Google / Internet?

Comment: Unrelated, but according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) the LLT applies for Mersenne number of the form `2**p - 1` **where p is an odd prime**. 65 is odd but not prime (5*13).

Comment: What do you actually pass to `lucas_lehmer_modified()`? Do you pass `61` or do you pass `2305843009213693951`?

Comment: It works well for me, if I pass `19`, which is the p for `524287` and it also works well for `61` which is the p for `2305843009213693951`. My feeling is that you pass M to the function instead of p.

Comment: For p=`19937`, the function already needs 18 seconds to run. Any higher numbers than that will likely cause a hang, so that's another indicator for me that you pass M instead of p.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Lucas Lehmer test from the psuedocode from the wikipedia entry, here is what i came up with ( p being the mersenne power number ):

```
def LucasLehmer(p):
   if p == 2:
     return True
   s = 4
   M = pow(2, p) - 1
   for x in range (1, (p-2)+1):
      s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
   if s == 0: return True
   else: return False
```

And some answers:

```
In [388]: LucasLehmer(9689)                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[388]: True

In [389]: LucasLehmer(19937)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[389]: True

In [390]: LucasLehmer(500)                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[390]: False
```